# Constructing the normal sheaf for the plucker embedding in MAGMA (or a similar programming language)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, computer-algebra

How would one construct the normal sheaf $N_{G(2,6)/\mathbb P^{14}}$ to the plucker embedding  of the grassmannian $G(2,6) \rightarrow \mathbb P^{14}$ as a sheaf in MAGMA (or another programming language)?

MAGMA has intrinsics for the tangent sheaf, cotangent sheaf, structure sheaf, etc., here: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1318.
However, I'm not sure how to construct the normal sheaf.

One thing that might be useful is that it would suffice to construct
$\wedge^2 S^\vee$ where $S$ is the universal sub-bundle of rank $4 = 6 - 2$, and $S^\vee$ is its dual. The reason for this is $N_{G(2,6)/\mathbb P^{14}} \cong \wedge^2 S^\vee \otimes \mathscr O_{G(2,6)}(1)$, according to page 51 of this paper: http://www.mat.ucm.es/invesmat/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/trabajo-master-curso-2009-10-tocino.pdf.

If it helps, the code for constructing the grassmannian G is particularly simple:

P<[x]> := ProjectiveSpace(PolynomialRing(Rationals(),15, "grevlex"));

mat := Matrix([[0, x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5]],[-x[1], 0,x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9]],[-x[2], -x[6],0,x[10],x[11],x[12]],[-x[3], -x[7],-x[10],0,x[13],x[14]],[-x[4], -x[8],-x[11],-x[13],0,x[15]],[-x[5], -x[9],-x[12],-x[14],-x[15],0]]);

G := Scheme(P, Pfaffians(mat,4));

I tried to construct the normal sheaf as the cokernel of the map of tangent sheaves
$T_{G(2,6)} \rightarrow T_{P^{14}}|_{G(2,6)}$, but I wasn't able to construct this map of sheaves, since MAGMA represents sheaves by a corresponding graded module, and I wasn't able to figure out the corresponding map of graded modules.
I also tried to construct the conormal sheaf as the kernel of
$\Omega_{P^{14}}|_{G(2,6)} \rightarrow \Omega_{G(2,6)}$, since it turned out that MAGMA's representation of these two sheaves were both quotients of graded modules of rank 105 over $k[x_1,\ldots, x_{15}]$. Unfortunately, the map induced by the $105 \times 105$ identity map was not a valid map, according to MAGMA.

Comment: I guess you can take the module associate with the ideal of Pfaffians(mat,4) and tensor with the coordinate ring of G, and then dualize. This will not give you the map, however.

Comment: Great point! This is exactly what I was looking for. I forgot about that, even though it's clearly the most obvious approach. Thanks!